# When unit testing what do you do when functions being called make SQL queries?

Tags: php, sql, unit-testing, phpunit

I have a function that looks like the following:

```
function putThis()
/*     * *********************************
  <summary>
  Function: putThis
  Purpose: Puts this in the database
  Inputs: None
  Outputs: None
  Notes:
  </summary>
 * ********************************* */ {
$err = $this->checkAll();
if ($err == '') {
    if ($this->isNew == true) {//create procedure
    $err = createSupportAccount($this);
    } else {//update
    $err = updateSupportAccount($this);
    }
}
return $err;
}
```

I am trying to do unit testing to ensure that the putThis() function is working properly. In this case the object is being passed on to a function which uses the object to make a database query. I could definitely fill the object with dummy data, however this means the function will return an error. Returning an error is not a problem if I am testing cases with invalid input data, but in the case I want to test that the function works correctly, how do I properly test it?

Comment: If you've abstracted your database layer, then you can mock it

Comment: @MarkBaker Mock which aspect of it?

Comment: If your code has instantiated a database connection, and then injects that object into your classes, you mock the database connection object and can inject that into your classes instead